# What is a "gilded shell" in Eliot's Wasteland?

Tags: literature

> A gilded shell
>
> Red and gold
>
> The brisk swell
>
> Rippled both shores

What is a "gilded shell" here? Some kind of boat?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of a "one-off" metaphor used in a poetic context.

Comment: @Fumble I'm not sure that it is obvious that "gilded shell" is a metaphor in this context.

Comment: @KitFox: Given the dictionaries of *gilded* and *shell*, I don't see how that collocation could ever be anything except "metaphor". So I suppose what you mean is from OP's perspective it might have been a (metaphoric) *established idiom*. But by that logic, any and all such questions *might* be thus interpreted, which may become a problematic issue. Maybe this specific question should be flagged up in meta to see what the consensus is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's the boat on which Elizabeth and Leicester are travelling down the Thames, so presumably Elizabeth's royal barge.

> Elizabeth and Leicester     
>   Beating oars    
>   The stern was formed    
>   A gilded shell  
>   Red and gold    
>   The brisk swell     
>   Rippled both shores     
>   South-west wind     
>   Carried down stream     
>   The peal of bells   
>   White towers

A royal barge would have been literally 'gilded' (covered in gold leaf).

[image: National Maritime Museum, Greenwich - Prince Frederick's Barge, Elliott Brown]

This royal barge is a bit later (1732) but it gives you some kind of an idea.

Image: [National Maritime Museum, Greenwich - Prince Frederick's Barge, Elliott Brown](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ell-r-brown/8145922817) ([CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/))

[The royal barge pictured is held at the National Maritime Museum in Greenwich](http://www.royalcollection.org.uk/collection/69797/royal-barge).

'Leicester' is [Robert Dudley, 1st Earl of Leicester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Dudley,_1st_Earl_of_Leicester), favourite of [Queen Elizabeth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_I_of_England).

'White towers': The White Tower is the keep of the [Tower of London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_London), where Leicester and Elizabeth had both been imprisoned, and where Leicester's father had been executed. The water-gate from the Thames to the Tower of London was (and is) the 'Traitors' Gate'.

In his notes on this section of the poem, Eliot refers to [The reign of Elizabeth, by James Anthony Froude](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/006065927). Eliot's note [reads](http://rpo.library.utoronto.ca/poems/waste-land#289):

> V. Froude, Elizabeth, Vol. I, ch. iv, letter of De Quadra to Philip of Spain:
>   "In the afternoon we were in a barge, watching the games on the river. (The queen) was 
>   alone with Lord Robert and myself on the 
>   poop, when they began to talk nonsense, and 
>   went so far that Lord Robert at last said, as 
>   I was on the spot there was no reason why they 
>   should not be married if the queen pleased."

The quoted letter is from Spanish ambassador Alvarez de Quadra to King Philip II of Spain. He was a bishop - during the boat ride he offered to marry Leicester to Elizabeth ("while I was on the spot").

At the time Eliot was writing, [the mainstream view of Leicester was](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Dudley,_1st_Earl_of_Leicester#Historiographical_treatment) that his influence on the queen was malignant and excessive, and that he was primarily concerned with his aspirations to marry her and rule the country:

> Leicester, consumed by his ambition to marry the queen, was an ornamental, if malignant, figure

Leicester and the Court: Essays on Elizabethan Politics, Simon Adams, [p.57](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-Nn5UY-RilEC&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A0719053250&pg=PA57#v=snippet&q=%22consumed%20by%20his%20ambition%20to%20marry%20the%20queen%22&f=false)

Comment: And if you're remembering the allusion in the previous section where "The Chair she sat in, like a burnished throne,/Glowed on the marble…" recalls Shakespeare's "The barge she sat in, like a burnish’d throne,/Burned on the water: the poop was beaten gold;" then you're already primed to hear about boats being decorated in gold.

Comment: Perhaps it was someone who recalled Shakespeare's "the poop was beaten gold" that came up with the derisive *gilding the turd* for making something look better than it is.